# Sputnik vs. moon

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

As the title suggests, can the word *sputnik* be used as a replacement for *moon* or *satellite* in **modern** English?

The reason why I am asking this is because I remember reading (probably in a history book) that the word *sputnik* was used for some time in English, after the launch of eponymous space probe.

Comment: First time on this SE site, poke me if I need to imrove something.

Comment: No. [Sputnik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_1) was the first man-made satellite, but it hasn't been a satellite for sixty years. And the usage of Sputnik for "satellite" was never common in (American) English.

Comment: Not really. *Sputnik* was the first artificial satellite. The Moon is a natural one. Talking about a *sputnik* does not make sense in English, even though it means *satellite* in Russian.

Comment: Very true, but I remember reading that the word *sputnik* had infiltrated English as a substitute for satellite, after the launch of eponymous probe.

Comment: It might have enjoyed a brief usage (in BrE) meaning *artificial satellite* (at least until the Americans got their own space program going), but it would never have meant *natural satellite*. I was only six years old at the time, so my memory is a little hazy.

Comment: @Mick  -  it does mean *natural satellite* in Russian. Can you make your comment to an answer?

Comment: I don't have the time right now. You are welcome to do it yourself if you like.

Comment: 'Sputnik' is now my shibboleth-of-the-day.  In the late 1950's, the media in the UK propelled this Russian word into the lexicon of that era. School kids, myself included, were particularly enamoured of it and of the lead taken by the Soviet space progamme over its US counterpart. Such was the Sputnik's impact on our popular culture at the time that if you didn't get a Sputnik toy or game in your Christmas stocking that year (late 1950's) you were quite obviously out of favor with Santa!

Comment: @PeterPoint I was 15 at the time, and I have to say that I have no such recollections. We were obviously aware of *sputnik*, but I can never remember any *Sputnik* toys or games. Perhaps I was too old and too much interested in acquiring my first pair of *drainpipe trousers* and shoes with thick soles - the Teddy-boy gear.

Comment: @Mick I was 15, and I don't remember the name being used generically for *artificial satellite* - certainly not for *moon*.

Comment: @WS2 I think you're right. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sputnik%2Csputnick&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSputnik%3B%2Cc0) gives no hits for *sputnik* (lower-case) in the BrE corpora, only *Sputnik*.

Comment: @WS2 Quite so!  In my case, at the age of 15, I was overcome with distractions too -- chronic acne! But I do recall that Sputnik-themed games and toys were all the rage at Christmas for a year or so. I also remember the Teddy Boy frenzy of the day when I was not yet a teenager. I seem to recall the shoes were referred to as Brothel Creepers - I can't imagine why!

Comment: I would have been 8 at the time.  I vaguely recall news headlines along the lines of "US Launches Its Own Sputnik" when Explorer 1 went up a few months later, but the term never gained much currency.  It was more often used figuratively as a sort of benchmark in the space race -- "Sputnik moment", eg.

Comment: @HotLicks  Quite so! I also remember Laika-the-dog in space, followed by Yuri and Valentina!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word ***sputnik*** does have an entry in the OED, in which both the capitalised and non-capitalised forms are mentioned. However from the examples given of the non-capitalised *sputnik*, I think it will be clear that it was not a general word for satellite but had a slightly ironic sense. **In one 1959 example from the *Daily Telegraph* the author has seen fit to put the word in quotation marks, which I think may be indicative of an attitude to its use in English at the time**.

I do not believe anything I have said here detracts from @Mick's answer in any way, and for which I have voted, since there is no evidence in the OED that it was in general use meaning an "artificial satellite".

> a. An unmanned artificial earth satellite, esp. a Russian one; spec.
>   (usu. with capital initial) the proper name of a series of such
>   satellites launched by the Soviet Union between 1957 and 1961.  The
>   first Sputnik, launched on 4 October 1957, was the first artificial
>   satellite.
>
> 1957   Times 9 Oct. 10/6   Pride in the launching of the sputnik
>   (‘fellow-traveller’), as the satellite is called, as well as the
>   guided missile, were reflected in a speech by Mr. Krushchev..last
>   night.
>
> 1957   Times 30 Oct. 10/2   Mr. Khrushchev replied: ‘To peace and to
>   the sputnik as a symbol of peace!’
>
> 1957   Times 4 Nov. 11/2   The régime which sends a second Sputnik
>   girdling the earth has just emerged from another of its secretly
>   contrived shifts of political power.
>
> 1958   A. Huxley Let. 15 Feb. (1969) 846   The technical advances in
>   these psychological, physiological and bio-chemical fields are
>   probably far more important..than the physical and engineering
>   advances which have put sputniks into the heavens.
>
> 1964   M. McLuhan Understanding Media iii. 44   When Sputnik had first
>   gone into orbit a schoolteacher asked her second-graders to write some
>   verse on the subject.
>
> 1971   New Scientist 10 June 638/1   China's remarkable progress in
>   the field is underscored by the weight of its first sputnik
>   (unmatched..by any satellite launched by France or Japan).
>
> 1983   N.Y. Times 7 Jan. a1/4   It is not a dangerous situation..and
>   we have no worries about the fate of this sputnik.
>
> b. transf. and fig.
>
> 1958   Newsweek 10 Feb. 25/1   We may find ourselves confronted with a
>   sputnik in the chemical, biological, and radiological field, as we did
>   in missiles.
>
> 1959   Daily Tel. 10 Dec. 16/7   Internal ‘sputniks’, pills containing
>   miniature radio transmitters, which can travel around the intestines.
>
> 1963   Punch 17 Apr. 549/1   Such Hollywood sputniks as Frank Sinatra
>   and Sammy Davis Jnr.
>
> 1968   Michelin Guide N.Y. City 124   Coney Island..scenic railways,
>   loop-the-loops and Ferris wheels compete with phantom trains, tunnels
>   of love, sputniks.

Answer (score 3):

The word *Sputnik* has no connotations in English as anything other than the original Soviet artificial satellite, Sputnik 1, and its successors.

[Wikipedia: List of spacecraft called Sputnik:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spacecraft_called_Sputnik)

> Sputnik (Спутник), a Russian word meaning "satellite" or literally
>   "fellow traveler", is a name applied to certain spacecraft launched
>   under the Soviet space program. "Sputnik 1", "Sputnik 2" and "Sputnik
>   3" were the official Soviet names of those objects, while the
>   remaining designations in the series ("Sputnik 4" and so on) were not
>   official names, but were names applied in the West, to objects whose
>   original Soviet names may not have been known at the time.

Although justifiably famous and obviously well-known at the time, the term *sputnik* has never gained any usage in the English-speaking world as a generic word for *satellite*, whether artificial or natural (e.g. the Moon).

A [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sputnik%2Csputnik&year_start=1900&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSputnik%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csputnik%3B%2Cc0) search for both *Sputnik* and *sputnik* gives the following results:

[image]

It is interesting that there is usage for both the capitalised and uncapitalised forms, although both usages dropped off in the early 1960s when the American manned space program started and the Sputnik program came to an end.

Answer (score 2):

In British English of the day (*circa* 1957-60), the Russian word *sputnik* became synonymous with the word *satellite* in the UK's media and lexicon, and was most definitely much more of a buzzword than its English language counterpart. Once the US space program caught up with and overtook its Russian counterpart, *sputnik* faded into the recesses of the ever changing popular lexicon of the era and was replaced exclusively by satellite. For this reason, I consider the word and its usage in English today to be a shibboleth.

**sputnik:** "Each of a series of Soviet artificial satellites, the first of which (launched on 4 October 1957) was the first satellite to be placed in orbit". (Oxford Dictionary)